# TextBlock to Display HTML in WPF

Tags: wpf, textblock

Is there anyway to display HTML from a string variable to the TextBlock in WPF?

Comment: can you be more specific? you want to display a block of HTML as HTML or as formatted (parsed) text?

Comment: I want to display a block of HTML as formatted text in a TextBlock! I am making a Rss Reader and want to display the description of the rss feed when the user clicks on the title. The description is bind to the TextBlock control.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can use this [WPF Html supported TextBlock](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33196/WPF-Html-supported-TextBlock)

Comment: This link is not more available. Pls, update your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Can't do it in TextBlock, you need a [WebBrowser control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.aspx) (or Frame, but it is obsolete). Feed descriptions, btw, can contain JavaScript - would be pretty hard for TextBlock to handle ;)

Answer (score 0):

string html = "`<div>hi</div>`
              `<div>&nbsp;</div>`
              `<p>this is the new line&nbsp;<br /><br />second line</p>`
               `<p>third line</p>`";

TextBlock.Text = Windows.Data.Html.HtmlUtilities.ConvertToText(html);

Comment: can you please explain where we should find the assembly where Windows.Data.Html.HtmlUtilities is located? I didn't find it in .net framework 4.0, thanks!

Comment: its a windows 10 only thing

Comment: the questions is about WPF and i think this answer is for UWP

Comment: @tabby is right...I have tried in UWP and it was working perfect

Comment: :( Can't call this from WPF for some reason (e.g. I can call some other UWP methods not problem) - makes app crash.