# How to change parts of the string in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, string

I am writing a c# wpf application that get information from rss feed. I got a string with "<'b>Bold Text<'/b> and <'i>Italic Text<'/i> and <'u>Underline text<'/u>" and need to change the font styles to the correct style when I want to use the string for a label or textbox. The output now would be like Label: <'b>Text<'/b> instead of Text being BOLD. Need help to find a way to fix it.

Comment: You should add sample string in your question, also what have you tried so far.

Comment: A string by itself doesn't have formatting.  What data are you _actually_ getting?

Comment: Its a bit confusing.. Can you please add a sample string.

Comment: Ah, now it makes sense.  You're receiving HTML data and you want to display it as HTML, not as text.  (Or find some similar styling equivalent.)

Comment: "String" is just a bunch of characters stored in memory. How that is displayed on the screen is up to the control you are using. You might want to take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.aspx - which supports formatting input...

Comment: textBox1.Font = new Font(textBox1.Font, FontStyle.Bold);

Comment: I don't need to change the whole textBox font only parts of it where there is HTML tags

Comment: Will this work for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1070996/textblock-to-display-html-in-wpf

Comment: you need to use regular expressions and remove all the html tags, in result it will give you list of all the values.

Comment: I already have Regex.Replace(oldText, @"<[^>]*>", String.Empty) to remove but I need to use it to change the font style instead of removing it.

Comment: do you have just <i> <u> <b> - or you also have more complex html tags with attributes (like <div height=...>) and you need to parse those as well ? If it's simple, you can parse this out even w/o regex. If it's more complex you might need HtmlAgilityPack

Comment: I just need to check on <i> <u> <b> the other html tags need to be deleted

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you got the following text:

```
<b>Bold</b><i>Italic</i>
```

You need to break the texts up and put them into WPF tags. That text in WPF must look like this:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Run Text="Bold" FontWeight="Bold" />
    <Run Text="Italic" FontStyle="Italic" />
</TextBlock>
```

If you google HTML to XAML convertion, you should find some API's or examples you can use:

[XAML to HTML Conversion Demo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa972129.aspx)

[HTML-XAML Converter](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2006/07/26/html_2d00_xaml-converter.aspx)